# Python - OSX - How to send a signal from an App bundled program?

Tags: python, macos, signals, py2app

I discovered that when I bundle my program with py2app I am not longer able to send signals to other apps.

I want to send a signal to "myself" to tell my process to perform something when user clicks my app after it is already running.

Here is some PyPseudo:

```
import signal, os, sys

if AlreadyRunning():
    daemonpid = GetPidOfMyOtherDaemon()
    os.kill(daemonpid, signal.SIGUSR1)
    sys.exit()

SaveMyPid()
# Here goes some other code, GUI or something
# That includes as well
def OnSIGUSR1 (signum, stackframe):
    print "I received SIGUSR1 just now!"
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, OnSIGUSR1)
```

Let say that GetPid...() and SaveMyPid() are storing and retrieving the pid of first started process in a file or somewhere.

Of course, I am not using print in my app, but even if I did, the message should appear in Console.

Well, this code is working perfectly when run from python or pythonw.

When I start it first time it does what it needs and waits for signal. When I start it again it sends a signal to itself and closes while first process receives the signal.

But it doesn't when I pack it into *.app with py2app.

The Console prints some LOL error like:

```
The process crashed because of some weird reason.
```

Which, of course, tells me nothing about what has really happened. :(

My App bundle does not run as LSUIElement = 1, nor as BackgroundOnly = 1. Should it?

Anyone knows why sending a signal doesn't work? Should I add something to info.plist?

Note: If I run it first time as an App, but second time from terminal with python/pythonw, it sends the signal to the running App normally and it receives it as well. So, os.kill() is a problem for sure.

Comment: I must admit my big mistake here. os.kill() works perfectly well from bundled app. The trouble is that the app will not start when it is clicked again. It doesn't matter whether the app is a background process or not. Mac OS X will not launch it again. You have to close the first instance of it to be able to start a new one. As I wanted to send a signal to myself from myself it didn't work because the second time I ran the app it didn't start at all. If the app in question was a GUI I would notice at once that clicking the icon again switches to already opened app.

Comment: I am now unsure whether to delete this Q or not. I mean, we learn from our mistakes, don't we?